# When the object is deleted?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x = 6;
    ~A() { std::cout << "\ndestr invoked\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    int* x;
    {
        A a;
        std::cout << &a.x << "\n";
        x = &a.x;
    }

    std::cout << x << ": " << *x;
}
```

With output:

```
0x78cac859fc00

destr invoked
0x78cac859fc00: 6
```

If I understand correctly it seems that destructor was invoked automatically but in memory variable remained. Does anyone know why?

In the following example (pointer was used so object was deleted manually):

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x = 6;
    ~A() { std::cout << "\ndestr invoked\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    int* x;
    {
        A* a = new A;
        std::cout << &a->x << "\n";
        x = &a->x;
        delete a;
    }

    std::cout << x << ": " << *x;
}
```

Variable was cleared:

```
Output:
0x1381360

destr invoked
0x1381360: 0
```

Does anyone know what the difference is?